# .htaccess - Virtual Directory for a single predefined file

Tags: .htaccess, directory

How would be the .htaccess lines to make a Virtual Directory from a single php File?

www.domain.de/file.php should go to www.domain.de/file/

Not all php files, only a single predefined in this Case the file.php

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^file.php$ file/ [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^file/ file.php [L]
Options -Indexes
```